# Adding Mybatis-spring-boot-starter to Maven error

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I added the `mybatis-spring-boot-starter` dependency to Maven `pom.xml`, but it gave error. Here is my parent POM and module POM, then my Maven `settings.xml`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's just the IDE. Is mvn clean package working?

Answer (score 0):

This is an IDE error, use the MVN command does not report an error, it does not matter